# Access Directory in Hibernate Search 5

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I still work with Bobo because of the limited faceting option in HSearch. 
Because of this I need to supply Bobo with a DirectoryReader for it to work.

Now I'm trying to upgrade to Hibernate Search 5 and my old way of getting that doesn't work anymore.

```
MutableSearchFactory factory = (MutableSearchFactory) fts.getSearchFactory();
DirectoryBasedIndexManager mgr = (DirectoryBasedIndexManager) factory.getAllIndexesManager().getIndexManager(clazz.getCanonicalName());

return DirectoryReader.open(mgr.getDirectoryProvider().getDirectory());
```

Any suggestions on how to get access to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it is a good idea to unwrap to `MutableSearchFactory`. This class is really internal. You are probably better of to unwrap to `SearchIntegrator` which is an API:

```
SearchIntegrator searchIntegrator = getSearchFactory().unwrap(SearchIntegrator.class );    
DirectoryBasedIndexManager indexManager = (DirectoryBasedIndexManager) searchIntegrator.getIndexManager(indexName)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this does the trick now

```
MutableSearchFactory factory = (MutableSearchFactory) fts.getSearchFactory().unwrap(MutableSearchFactory.class);

DirectoryBasedIndexManager mgr = (DirectoryBasedIndexManager) factory.getAllIndexesManager().getIndexManager(clazz.getCanonicalName());
```